# Product synchronization in yahoo auction japan

Tags: laravel-5, e-commerce, yahoo-api

I have a ecommerce app in laravel from where i want to add/edit/update/delete product in http://auctions.yahoo.com. I have searched their api http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/auctions/ but no luck. So my question is anybody has idea of product synchronization in yahoo auction  if yes then please help me answering your experience. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

There are some APIs not listed there(e.g. [add item](https://developer-ec.yahoo.co.jp/promo/submit_api/)). Those API requires individual contract with YahooJapan, and those contracts are open only to the corporate at this moment. Once you made the contract with them, they will disclose all the necessary documents for you.